# Turkish character error in project name in api level 31 and above in React native to Android Project to emulator

Tags: react-native, crash, non-ascii-characters, android-api-levels, application-name

I created a project with a React Native Turkish name. My project Name "Şifre". Since there is a Turkish character in the name I have given in the strings.xml file, the project does not work on Android Emulator devices with API level 31 and above. But project work to reel devices. When I change my project name with 'Sifre' or 'sifre' so, name without turkish characters.

I SPECIFICALLY POINT OUT : THIS PROBLEM IS ONLY EMULATOR(API 31 LEVEL AND ABOVE). IT WORKING PROBABLY TO REEL DEVİCES.

I applied the following solution method (to strings.xml file) but my project doesn't work.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  or <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

I'm leaving a screenshot for clarity. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

[image]

My Solutions:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the project name is translated into Turkish, I encounter this error in api level 31 and higher emulators, but the real hardware is the project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).